# In grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : failed to load cairo DLL

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I have used ggsave to save png's a million times and I think this has to do with upgrading to R 3.5, not sure, but now I cannot do so anymore. Why has this stopped working?

```
library(ggplot2)
qq = c(1,2)
rr = c(1,2)
dd = data.frame(x=qq,y=rr)
pp = ggplot(dd, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line()
ggsave(filename = "pp.png", plot = hists, path = plotPath, device = 
"png", width = 6, height = 4, units = "in")
```

And I get

> Warning message:
>   In grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : failed to load cairo DLL

And the plot does not save.  What gives?  Yesterday I spent a long time repairing svg file saving but I was lucky enough to have the right library files on my computer in another place, which I could distinguish from the error messages, search and find on my computer, but here I got nothing.  I installed `cairo` via `brew install cairo` as suggested but did not help.

Comment: Don't you want `plot=pp` rather than `plot=hists`?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, still fails the same way

Comment: When I load the R-package Cairo I get this : `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Cairo’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Cairo', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I was looking at the R documentation on cran and as it turns out the installation on this machine via the updater did not account for the fact one needs Xquartz to run x11 for R 3.5.  Once xquartz was installed birds started chirping, elephants trumpeting and monkey, well, Ok, we'll stop there...